How is separation ensured after a go-around due to a busy runway
In watching aviation / ATC videos, I've often seen situations like the following: airplane A is coming in to land, but airplane B is already on the same runway trying to take off. Either it's slow taking off, or the controller did not provide enough separation, or for whatever reason the pilot of airplane A is not comfortable with this situation, so airplane A executes a go-around.
At the moment this happens, both planes are presumably moving exactly along the direction of the runway, plane B being slow (just taking off) and plane A being fast (doing a go-around).  So presumably plane A will at some point overtake plane B, making the horizontal separation between them zero. Both airplanes are climbing. How is vertical separation between them ensured?
Or does the going-around plane turn right away? In which case, isn't there a problem with a possible stall? Also is the turn heading somehow pre-determined in advance (because I'd imagine there wouldn't be time to ask the controller in a go-around situation)?

It depends on... so many circumstances. You have regulation and procedures for almost each classic airport. You have trained pilots, ie, go-arounds are "professionally performed with separation" in the first place, you don't go-around too late. For similar aircraft, departing ones are heavy, arriving ones are light (burnt fuel), a go around has an higher climb rate than a taking-off plane, separation includes vertical. Yes, conflicts do happen, ranting pilots aswell (on radio), but actual close calls are extremely rare for airliners. General aviation side at uncontrolled airfields however...

Interesting coincidence: Kelsey from the 74 Gear channel just alluded to this in https://youtu.be/sXY2gFn6cI0. He discusses a situation where a controller tries to squeeze a departing aircraft in between two landing aircraft, the second aircraft goes around, and then the controller gets angry. He then recounts a similar situation where he chose to land instead of going around precisely because of the  potential conflict you are asking about.

A note for you, @Jörg: I wasn't there and I don't know the details of how JFK works, but if the controller says "it would have been tight but it would have worked" I would tend to believe that. One very important piece of information is that it IS legal to have two aircraft over the runway at the same time, depending on certain details, and the controller was almost certainly planning on using that rule to the fullest.

There are a lot of different ways this can play out, and the details matter. I will be answering in the context of faa-regulations.
One point before I go further is that visual separation is a thing, and a very common thing in the usa at least. This can be tower-applied visual separation, where the controller has the aircraft in sight and issues instructions to ensure they don't conflict, or pilot-applied visual separation, where one pilot has the other in sight and maneuvers as necessary to avoid a conflict. In either case separation is allowed to reduce below the "standard" separation requirements.
In situations where visual separation cannot be used, the general rule is that aircraft need to be three miles apart. But this is allowed to reduce to only two miles if one is departing and the other is arriving, provided separation will increase to three miles within one minute after departure. This two-mile minimum must exist at the time the aircraft on the runway begins its takeoff roll.
Even in situations where visual separation can be used there are still minimum distance rules between an arrival and a departure using the same runway—these minimums can't be replaced by visual separation. Legal separation can be as low as 1.0, 0.75, or even 0.5 miles depending on the weight and engine configuration of the aircraft involved (using weight and configuration as a proxy for speed).
My point with the above is that your presumption

plane A will at some point overtake plane B, making the horizontal separation between them zero

does not really hold true in the majority of situations. Very occasionally a controller will make a bad blunder and it can happen, as shown in this recent video. In a case like that it's a lot hairier and the controller should be on top of the situation issuing traffic calls and vectors to pry the airplanes apart. As can be seen, if the controller is slow to react an onboard system called TCAS will alert the pilots to the impending collision and will issue instructions which override ATC instructions. All airliners and many larger business jets have TCAS these days.
But most of the time the controller will act much sooner—the video above is really the exception which proves the rule. Standard separation has quite a lot of buffer built in; if the controller does suffer a loss of separation there is still plenty of time to rectify the situation and prevent a collision. Even if it takes a few seconds for them to react it's almost never the case that the aircraft going around will catch up to the aircraft departing, provided the two aircraft are of similar performance classes.

As for actual methods to prevent a collision:

The classic is to instruct the go-around to "offset left/right of the runway." This isn't a standard instruction found in the controller rulebook but it is a very common one "in the field," especially at towers which work a lot of aircraft in the VFR pattern; of course this is a bad idea if the weather is bad and the pilots can't see any obstructions near them. This instruction all but guarantees the aircraft won't hit, provided the go-around offsets to the opposite side relative to where the departure is turning.
If an offset isn't possible the controller can issue turns to avoid conflict; the go-around turns away from the departure and vice-versa. Again this can less effective in bad visibility because pilots will need to gain altitude before being comfortable turning away from the obstacle-free area along the runway centerline. (There are published missed approach procedures but in most cases ATC will issue a vector instead of allowing the published missed, which likely won't provide the immediate separation they need and often conflicts with other streams of aircraft too.)
The go-around can be issued a climb to above the altitude the departure is climbing to, and/or the departure can be stopped at a lower altitude than they were issued initially. Most of the time they'll need to keep climbing very soon in order to avoid obstacles or terrain on the ground, but a short level-off is better than being run over by the go-around...

